# Firebase logIn part of authentication not returning anything and observer not triggered

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am looking to implement an authentication system using firebase in a react native application. When signing up, the user is added to the firebase database list of accounts, however the user is not signed in. When calling `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` nothing happens. No error, no result, nothing. It's like the function is not called at all. Also, the observer `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` doesn't seem to "fire" no matter what. My domain is authorized (it's localhost... ) and read and write permissions are allowed.

Code:

```
function receiveDataForSignUp(email,password){
    if(email && password) {
        console.log("Received data for sign up");

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.code);
            console.log(error.message);
        });
    }
    return false;
}

function receiveDataForLogIn(email,password){
    if(email && password) {
        console.log("Data received for log in " + email + " " + password );

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.code);
                console.log(error.message);
            });
    }

}

function logOutUser(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
}



function updateUser() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) { //user signed in
            userId = user.uid;
            console.log("User signed in");
        } else {
            console.log("User not signed in");
        }
        console.log("This is not printed either")
    });
}
```

These are all functions which are sent as callback to form components. The functions work as it's proven by the fact that the console log for "data received for log in " works. I've tried adding .then blocks with the .catch blocks, but it looks like they are not accessed either. Before the given code i have declared the firebase requirements

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "#####",
    authDomain: "####",
    databaseURL: "#####",
    projectId: "#####",
    storageBucket: "#####",
    messagingSenderId: "######",
    appId: "#######"
};

var userId=null;
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I think i am not receiving the Promise, but i am not sure and i have no idea how to fix it. I am also using Node.JS if relevant. Looking for any ideas that could help a stuck programmer. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem and for anyone encountering something similar - my problem was that the page refreshed because i didn't call `event.preventDefault()` in my forms. Now it looks like it is working. I have no idea why as if i do refresh after log in, everything is ok.